# Is only fgets() best avoided in binary mode?

Tags: c, character

Wikipedia says:

> The C library function fgets() is best avoided in binary mode because
>   any file not written with the UNIX newline convention will be misread.

Is only  fgets()   best avoided in binary mode?
How about other C library functions for reading files?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a function that is meant to read a line of _text_. It has no business being used for a binary file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fgets()` reads a line of text, terminated by a single `'\n'` newline character (or a partial line if the next input line is longer than the buffer you're using).

When used on a text stream, an actual end-of-line marker, however it's represented, is converted to a single `'\n'` character, so `fgets()` will work as expected.

`fgets()` is far less likely to be useful on a binary stream. It will still read characters up to the end of the buffer or up to the first `'\n'` byte, whichever appears first.  If that happens to be what you want to do, there's no particular reason not to use `fgets()`.

The contents of a binary file have whatever meaning you assign to them. If a given binary file uses `'\n'` as a delimiter -- whether that happens to be the system's end-of-line marker *for text files* or not -- then `fgets()` will probably work.

But if you have a binary file with records(?) marked by `'\n'` characters, I have to wonder why it wasn't a text file in the first place.

`fgets()` is *intended* to be used to read lines from a text stream, but the way it works is rigorously defined by the C standard. It's defined to work *as if* by repeatedly calling `fgetc()`.

If it happens to be useful for something else, feel free to use it. But any slight change in your requirements, like using a character other than `'\n'` as the delimiter, is likely to mean that `fgets()` will no longer work.

Just for the sake of clarity, you're probably better of writing a custom function that does what you want with binary input.